# Primefaces Subtable to get row index

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, primefaces-datatable

I am using PrimeFaces 6.0 in my project to `dataTable` inside `subTable` has to be used. I need how to get row index inside the `subTable`

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="team" value="#{dtSubTableView.teams}" rowIndexVar="teamIndexVar">
        <f:facet name="header">
            NBA Teams
        </f:facet>

        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Team" />
                <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Stats" />
            </p:row>
            <p:row>
                <p:column headerText="Wins" />
                <p:column headerText="Losses" />
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>

        <p:subTable var="stats" value="#{team.stats}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{team.name}" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{stats.season}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{stats.win}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton id="editButton" value="Edit" />
            </p:column>

        </p:subTable>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I need when I press command button to pass current index inside `subTable`.

Comment: Why don't you pass id (assuming: teamId as primary key) of your `team` object?

Comment: @ParkashKumar Based on index to control the  rendered property also

Comment: What if you set `rowIndexVar="teamIndex"`on `p:dataTable` and use within `p:subTable` for `rendered` attribute?

Comment: In first column try to set rowspan but it's not working so now I try subTable index  0 to set rendered property